# How to solve my Touchpad problem

Tags: touchpad, asus

I use a Asus X550LD laptop. On installing ubuntu or any other linux based ROMs I find that the touchpad doesn't work. The cursor moves towards the left by itself too. I've tried using an external mouse; but that doesn't seem to help.  When I searched about it, I found out that many others also seem to have this problem. Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating drivers.In additional Drivers option.
or download the driver for your touch-pad and install in manually